# RegionPlot with rank constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, regions

I am trying to plot the feasible region of a rank constrained semidefinite program shown below:

[image: Rank Constrained SDP]

The Mathematica code that I am using is the following:

```
FeasibleRegionRanksdp =
  RegionPlot[
    Tr[{{0.09, 0}, {0, 7}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
    Tr[{{7, 0}, {0, 0.09}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
    Tr[{{1.05, -0.95}, {-0.95, 1.05}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
    Tr[{{1.05, 0.95}, {0.95, 1.05}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
    MatrixRank[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}, Tolerance -> 0] ==1 && 
    Min[Eigenvalues[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}]] >= 0,
    {x1, -0.5, 0.5}, {x2, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

The result that I am obtaining is the following non-convex region:

[image: Rank Constrained SDP Feasible Region]

My questions is:

1) Is the rank constraint imposed correctly in Mathematica?

2) Is the positive semidefiniteness constraint also correct in the code?

based on my understanding, the rank constraint is the only non-convex constraint and so the region should be non convex. But once I remove the rank constraint, the non convexity should be removed and the region should be convex which is not the case as could be checked by removing the rank constraint and plotting.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider pre-evaluating your region descriptor conditions:

```
regiondescriptor = 
 Tr[{{0.09, 0}, {0, 7}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
 Tr[{{7, 0}, {0, 0.09}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 && 
 Tr[{{1.05, -0.95}, {-0.95, 1.05}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 &&
 Tr[{{1.05, 0.95}, {0.95, 1.05}}.{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}] <= 1 &&
 MatrixRank[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}, Tolerance -> 0] == 1 && 
 Min[Eigenvalues[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}]] >= 0

(* Out: 0.09 x1^2 + 7 x2^2 <= 1 && 
        7 x1^2 + 0.09 x2^2 <= 1 && 
        1.05 x1^2 - 1.9 x1 x2 + 1.05 x2^2 <= 1 && 
        1.05 x1^2 + 1.9 x1 x2 + 1.05 x2^2 <= 1 && 
        Min[0, x1^2 + x2^2] >= 0 *)
```

Then use the evaluated version in `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[regiondescriptor, {x1, -0.5, 0.5}, {x2, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I cannot guarantee that this is a correct representation of your problem, since your problem is presented in a symbolic form that I do not completely understand, so I will leave it to you or others to determine whether this is an appropriate answer to your problem. Perhaps you could reformulate the problem in a less terse form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Based on the output from the regiondescriptor (included as a comment), it seems that the MatrixRank is not being evaluated since it is not showing up in the output. Maybe the problem is in the rank constraint.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKalbat The `MatrixRank` is actually being evaluated, but it identically evaluates to `True` no matter the values of `x1` and `x2` (check `MatrixRank[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}, Tolerance -> 0] == 1`, or `Det[{{x1^2, x1*x2}, {x1*x2, x2^2}}]`, which is zero), so it is simplified out of the logical expression.

Comment: you are right. The formulation is not correct and the rank will always be equal to one. Instead of the rank constraint and the positive semidefinitness contraints, I could replace them by introducing a new matrix variable X that is defined as follows: X = x * x^T  where the vector x=[x1  x2]. After defining this matrix variable, all other constraints should defined in terms of this matrix variable. New code is following but not working:

Comment: regiondescriptor = 
 Tr[{{0.09, 0}, {0, 7}}.X] <= 1 && Tr[{{7, 0}, {0, 0.09}}.X] <= 1 && 
  Tr[{{1.05, -0.95}, {-0.95, 1.05}}.X] <= 1 && 
  Tr[{{1.05, 0.95}, {0.95, 1.05}}.X] <= 1  && 
  X == Transpose[{x1, x2}].{x1, x2}

RegionPlot[regiondescriptor, {x1, -10, 10}, {x2, -10, 10}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Black]

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKalbat Mathematica does not distinguish between row and column vectors, so start by defining `X = {x1, x2}.{x1, x2}` instead, then use that in your `regiondescriptor`. I am still confused though: what did you think the explicit form of `X` would be in your code? `X` seems to be defined as the scalar `x1^2 + x2^2`.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKalbat Perhaps, rather than trying to fix your code, you could try to modify the description of your problem, providing a plain English explanation of your conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41837/discussion-between-abdulrahman-kalbat-and-marcob).